# When does a binomial have repeated roots mod p?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Given a polynomial $f(x)=x^n+a$, and I have that $p$ does not divide $an$, can I show that $f(x)\pmod p$ has no repeated roots? I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What repeated roots does mean?

Comment: That $f(x)\pmod p$ can be factored into $(x-b)^2g(x)\pmod p$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose there are repeated roots. Then $f$ and $f'$ would have at least one common root ($f'$ is the formal derivative). Because $f' = nx^{n-1}$ and $p$ does not divide $n$ the only root of $f'$ is $0$. But $0$ is not a root for $f$ because $p$ does not divide $a$